# Elixir: pattern matching two same arguments to a function

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm iterating through a list of strings, and I want to return the contents of a string if the beginning of it matches the provided string.

e.g.

```
strings = [ "GITHUB:github.com", "STACKOVERFLOW:stackoverflow.com" ]
IO.puts fn(strings, "GITHUB") // => "github.com"
```

This is what I thinking so far:

```
def get_tag_value([ << tag_name, ": ", tag_value::binary >> | rest ], tag_name), do: tag_value

def get_tag_value([ _ | rest], tag_name), do: get_tag_value(rest, tag_name)

def get_tag_value([], tag_name), do: ""
```

But I get this:

```
** (CompileError) lib/file.ex:31: a binary field without size is only allowed at the end of a binary pattern and never allowed in binary generators
```

Which makes sense, but then I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. How would I match a substring to a different variable provided as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this making most use of pattern matching and no call to `String.starts_with?` or `String.split`:

```
defmodule A do
  def find(strings, string) do
    size = byte_size(string)
    Enum.find_value strings, fn
      <<^string::binary-size(size), ":", rest::binary>> -> rest
      _ -> nil
    end
  end
end

strings = ["GITHUB:github.com", "STACKOVERFLOW:stackoverflow.com"]

IO.inspect A.find(strings, "GITHUB")
IO.inspect A.find(strings, "STACKOVERFLOW")
IO.inspect A.find(strings, "GIT")
IO.inspect A.find(strings, "FOO")
```

Output:

```
"github.com"
"stackoverflow.com"
nil
nil
```

Comment: Is is possible to write that anonymous function in Enum.find_value as not anonymous?

Comment: After seeing your answer I've been trying this same function out with passing in the size as well and not really been getting it to work, e.g. `def get_tag_value(list, tag_name), do: _get_tag_value, tag_name, byte_size(tag_name)` but I couldn't find a way to get that working

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in a function head. `size` needs to be defined before the function which means either an anonymous function like my answer or a module attribute (which doesn't apply here). `def find_recursive(size, string, [<<string::size(size), rest::binary>> | tail]), do: rest` throws a compile error: `variable size@1 is unbound`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

For example:

```elixir
def get_tag_value(tag, strings) do
  strings
  |> Enum.find("", &String.starts_with?(&1, tag <> ":"))
  |> String.split(":", parts: 2)
  |> Enum.at(1, "")
end
```

or if you still wanted to explicitly use recursion:

```elixir
def get_tag_value(_tag, []), do: ""

def get_tag_value(tag, [str | rest]) do
  if String.starts_with?(str, tag <> ":") do
    String.split(str, ":", parts: 2) |> Enum.at(1, "")
  else
    get_tag_value(tag, rest)
  end
end
```

Are just two of many possible ways.

However, you won't be able to pattern match the string in the function head without knowing it (or at least the length) beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
iex(1)> strings = [ "GITHUB:github.com", "STACKOVERFLOW:stackoverflow.com" ]

iex(2)> Enum.filter(strings, fn(s) -> String.starts_with?(s, "GITHUB") end)
iex(3)> |> Enum.map(fn(s) -> [_, part_2] = String.split(s, ":"); part_2 end)

# => ["github.com"]
```

In [Enum.filter/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) I select all strings they start with "GITHUB" and I get a new [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html). [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) iterates through the new [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) and splits each string at the colon to return the second part only. Result is a [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) with all parts after the colon, where the original string starts with "GITHUB".

Be aware, that If there's an item like "GITHUBgithub.com" without colon, you get a MatchError. To avoid this either use `String.starts_with?(s, "GITHUB:")` to filter the right strings or avoid the pattern matching like I did in [Enum.map/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) or use pattern matching for an empty list like @ryanwinchester did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of Enum.map and Enum.filter to get the matching pairs you're looking for:

```
def get_tag_value(tag_name, tags) do
  tags
  |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ":")) # Creates a list of [tag_name, tag_value] elements
  |> Enum.filter(fn([tn, tv]) -> tn == tag_name end) # Filters for the tag name you're after
  |> List.last # Potentially gets you the pair [tag_name, tag_value] OR empty list
end
```

And in the end you can either call `List.last/1` again to either get an empty list (no match found) or the tag value.

Alternatively you can use a case statement to return a different kind of result, like a `:nomatch` atom:

```
def get_tag_value(tag_name, tags) do
  matches = tags
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, ":")) # Creates a list of [tag_name, tag_value] elements
    |> Enum.filter(fn([tn, tv]) -> tn == tag_name end) # Filters for the tag name you're after
    |> List.last # Potentially gets you the pair [tag_name, tag_value] OR empty list
  case matches do
    [] -> :nomatch
    [_, tag_value] -> tag_value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my take in Erlang:

```
get_tag_value(Tag, Strings) ->
    L = size(Tag),
    [First | _] = [Val || <<Tag:L/binary, $:, Val/binary>> <- Strings]
    First.
```

The same in Elixir (there are probably more idiomatic ways of writing it, tho):

```
def gtv(tag, strings) do
  l = :erlang.size(tag)
  [first | _ ] =
    for << t :: binary - size(l), ":", value :: binary >> <- strings,
        t == tag,
        do: value
  first
end
```